# How can you import CSS into a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Say you have a CSS file with the code:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
}
```

And the HTML file index.html.
How could you create a server that takes index.html and adds the CSS?
Edit:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function sendFile(res, filename, type) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end();
            return
                ;
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': type });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        sendFile(res, "index.html", "text/html");
    } 
    else if (req.url == "/styles.css") {
        sendFile(res, "styles.css", "text/css");
    } 
    else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You can either insert the CSS directly into `index.html` yourself.  Or, if you want to put the CSS in a separate file such as `styles.css`, then you need to code your http server so that it servers both `index.html` and `styles.css`.  Since you don't show any of your web server code, we can't really help more specifically than that.  Please show your existing http server code that serves `index.html`.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I have:
```javascript
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to put your code into your question so your question properly shows what your code is.  Multi-line code in comments is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is a lot simpler with a simple framework like Express where you can configure it to automatically serve a directory of static files.

But, if you want to do it yourself using only the built-in http object, you can do something like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

function sendFile(res, filename, type) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': type });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url === "/") {
        sendFile(res, "index.html", "text/html");
    } else if (req.url === "/styles.css") {
        sendFile(res, "styles.css", "text/css");
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Then, inside of `index.html`, you can have:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="/styles.css"  rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red">This is some text that is supposed to be red</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In `styles.css`, you can have:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

That will cause the browser to request `/styles.css` and your web server will be configured to serve that file for that request.

Comment: jfriend00 so now i have the edited code but it still doesn't work

Comment: @two - "Still does not work" does not give us anything to go on.  What troubleshooting did you do?  What did you learn?  What errors did you see?  What HTML are you using?  Since you've shown none of that, there's nothing else we can provide except to say that the code I show in my answer works just fine for me.  Perhaps you can use that as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry, but now I have got it working, I just had to rename "styles" to "style".
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @two - Glad you got it figured out.  Since it looks like you may be a bit new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by l clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points.